# Best approach to use nested reducer in React-Redux If same store value are used on same page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am using same filter two time same screen for different purpose. Now updating at one place automatically updates the dependent values on second filter as well.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need two states in your Redux store - one for each filter. Then you need to connect one state to one filter, and the other state to the other filter.

You don't need to duplicate your reducers and actions though. Your action could take an filterId as input, and then pass this down to the reducer. The reducer updates different states based on which filterId is passed in from the action.

Hope that makes sense! Feel free to add follow up questions or additional information about your problem to get a more detailed explanation!

Comment: But in this way code will be redundant. I need to repeat all action and reducers. Also I am using same filters on some other pages. How I will maintain. Please make me correct If I am wrong.

Comment: Your action could take an filterId as input, and then pass this down to the reducer. The reducer updates different states based on which filterId is passed in from the action. (I also updated my original answer now)

Comment: Your answer make sense for me.  Let me explain more.
I have three reducer Compound, Block and Building and having three action for same. 
Compound have compounds key. Block have blocks key. and Building have buildings key. These key I am using for listing pages.
Now according to you I need to take another two keys like fiter1 and filter2 in each reducer.
So I am worry if in future I have some more filter or anything similar. So not sure may be that will goes more complex to handle action type and save in reducer.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any other suggestion, Otherwise I am happy with your answer. 
Thank you